# How to drop down menu wordpress only css

Tags: css, wordpress

I need make a wordpress menu with css only (dropdown style menu)

i can't find the correct way maybe the error its on the classes assigned but i already try some options and none fix the problem, with this code i can see the menu but never display the items and subitems would be great some help

This is the wordpress tag and codes and also the css used

```
************************************ 
             MENU
************************************
<label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
    <nav id="superior">
            <?php wp_nav_menu(
            array(
            'container'=> false,
            'items_wrap'     => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s nav nav-pills"> %3$s</ul>',
            'theme_location' => 'menu'
            )); ?>
    </nav>  

************************************
             .CSS
************************************

/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
}
/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #2f3036;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
    background: #c3c3c3;
}
/*Style for dropdown links*/
ul li:hover ul a {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #2f3036;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #19c589;
    color: #fff;
}
/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}
/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}
/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #19c589;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
}
/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}
/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}
/*Responsive Styles*/
@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
    }
    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }
    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

html generated:

```
<header>

<label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
    <nav id="superior">
            <ul id="menu-menu" class="menu nav nav-pills"> <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-18"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/" aria-current="page">Inicio</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-130" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-130"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/category/mejores-tal-cosa/">Mejores tal cosa</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-132" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-has-children menu-item-132"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/que-es-lorem-ipsum/">Que es Lorem Ipsum?</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-131" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-131"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/category/destacados/">Destacados</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-19"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/pagina-ejemplo/">Página de ejemplo</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/contacto/">Contacto</a></li>
</ul>   </nav>  

</header>
```

Comment: can you post the HTML that is wp_nav_menu is generating?  Just so we can know it's outputting correctly and all the css is applied correctly.

Comment: hi, thanks for the interest, i already update the code with the html generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the .hidden classes to .sub-menu and it's working.  Not sure if it's the exact functionality you're looking for:

changed:

```
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

to:

```
ul li a:hover + .sub-menu, .sub-menu:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

https://codepen.io/jfitzsimmons/pen/oNvZwEm